# Print Qt C++ output to app screen written in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

My Qt C++ code generates list of available Bluetooth devices and I want to print it to the app screen which is created using QML. I am able to print the available devices to the qDebug output, but how do I print it to the QML generated screen?

If someone can point me to the right resource that would be really helpful too.

After these Bluetooth devices are displayed on the app screen I intend to connect to whichever device is selected by the user.

I am having a really hard time in understanding the interface between C++ and QML. I am fairly new to Qt and I am adding features to a large project written by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I use Qt using UI Editor and C++, but with QML is exactly the same. I recomend you to use a QListView with a custom model with your bluetooth devices.  A little example with some devices:

```
const QStringList devices = QStringList() << "Samsumng S5" << "Iphone 4S" << "Xiami Mi3";
```

Now, we will create our list model:

```
QStringListModel *listModel = new QStringListModel(this);
listModel->setStringList(devices);
```

Finally, set the model as the default model in our list view:

```
ui->lisView->setModel(listModel);
```

Now, how to handle the selected device? Use the available signals of the listview selection model (QItemSelectionModel), like

```
void currentRowChanged(const QModelIndex &current, const QModelIndex &previous)
```

Handle the signal with a custom slot and do what you want! =)